# How do I deal with StackExchange.Redis ConnectTimeout

Tags: .net, redis, stackexchange

We have a .Net Core application,SDK version is 3.1.401,and Redis component is StackExchange.Redis,version is 2.6.90.
In product environment,we found variety of error as below:

```
2023-05-18 12:07:12,933 [1530] ERROR colsrv - Create ConnectionMultiplexer error ^M
It was not possible to connect to the redis server(s). Error connecting right now. To allow this multiplexer to continue retrying until it's able to connect, use abortConnect=false in your connection string or AbortOnConnectFail=false; in your code. ConnectTimeout
```

our program had been set Threadpool min threads as 10000 and 500(ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(10000,500))
because we had much more query request to redis(almost are concurrency operation),we havne't found a solution yet,could you help me?

Sorry for my poor english

Becaues we haven't found solution,we plan to recreate redis connect object when we found more than 10 times 'connection error'.

Comment: You can always use translate or other AI tools to help you smooth the edges of the rough edges of your sentences. "Rephrase my sentence" gives you "We set the Threadpool min threads as 10000 and 500 (`ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(10000,500)`) because we had many query requests to Redis (almost all of them are concurrent operations). We haven’t found a solution yet. Can you help us?"